# how to make it so each number to n will print on a seperate line, and beside it will have either abundant, deficient or perfect in C++?

Tags: c++

Ok basically that gets a number from 1 to n and prints all of them if they are abundant, deficient or perfect numbers.  how to make it so each number to n will print on a seperate line, and beside it will have either abundant, deficient or perfect in C++?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int range1,range2;
    range1 = 1;
    cout<<"Enter a range:";
    cin>>range2;
    cout<<"Abundant numbers between "<<range1<<" and "<<range2<<" are: ";
    for(int j=range1;j<=range2;j++)
    {
    int sum=0;
    for(int i=1;i<j;i++)
    {
        if(j%i==0)
        {
            sum=sum+i;
        }
    }

   if(sum>j)
    cout<<j<<" ";
    }

    cout << "\n"<<endl;
    cout<<"\nDeficient numbers between "<<range1<<" and "<<range2<<" are: ";
    for(int j=range1;j<=range2;j++)
    {
    int sum=0;
    for(int i=1;i<j;i++)
    {
        if(j%i==0)
        {
            sum=sum+i;
        }
    }

   if(sum<j)
    cout<<j<<" ";
    }
  
    cout << "\n"<<endl;
    cout<<"\nPerfect numbers between "<<range1<<" and "<<range2<<" are: ";
    for(int j=range1;j<=range2;j++)
    {
    int sum=0;
    for(int i=1;i<j;i++)
    {
        if(j%i==0)
        {
            sum=sum+i;
        }
    }

   if(sum==j)
    cout<<j<<" ";
    }



}
```

Comment: first of all make functions that decide on a property of a number, then you can either can make one loop and call each of those functions. Or you can first fill arrays with precalculated values before printing them. Your question is more on how do I write a program, then how to write C++. Also : unlearn "using namespace std;" very very quickly (google on this and you will find out why)

Comment: Thanks for your feedback and prompt response @PepijnKramer

Comment: What is your current obstacle to completing your assignment? You might start by showing us your current output, along with your desired output. But even then, focus a bit. There are at least two steps mentioned in your question: "print on a seperate line" and "if they are abundant, deficient or perfect". These steps are disjoint; each can be done independently of the other. Once you have both steps solved, there is a third step of combining the solutions. Which step are you stuck on? Can you narrow it down even more?

Answer (score 0):

To make each number print on a separate line, insert `\n` after the number.